# In the normal distribution table I find different values ​for one number

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

In the normal distribution table I find different values, for example 2.22 has two values ​​of 0.9861 and in another table 0.4868 how is that

Comment: they represent different things

Comment: My guess is you mistakenly looked at the entry for $2.2$ when you found $0.9861$. The correct entry in that table would be $0.9868.$

Answer (score 0):

There are two common conventions for a table of values of the standard normal distribution. One convention is that a number in the table represents the area of the entire region under the curve to the left of the input value.
The other convention is that a number in the table represents only the area under the curve between $0$ and the input value.

In other words, one table lets you choose $z$ and then look up the value of the integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm dt. $$

Another table lets you look up the value of the integral

$$ \int_0^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm dt. $$

A result from the first table should always be equal to $\frac12$ plus the corresponding result from the second table,
because the difference between the two integrals is

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm dt = \frac 12. $$

Sometimes in a calculation the result from the first table will be more convenient; sometimes the result from the second table will be more convenient.
But you can always convert one table's value to the other just by adding or subtracting $0.5.$